# Struts2 on Websphere

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, struts2, websphere

I have a Struts2 application what is working fine with Eclipse, and I also tried it on plain Tomcat6 web server (copied .war file to webapps folder).

But after deploying the .war file on WebSphere Application Server, the following error is received during committing a form in the application:

Any idea how to solve it?

```
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception



root cause 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ognl/SimpleNode.isEvalChain(Lognl/OgnlContext;)Z
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.isEvalExpression(OgnlUtil.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:214)
```

Comment: There is some old OGNL dependency in the classpath, remove it.

Comment: When the war file is generated the war file contains an ognl-3.0.5.jar file. I tried to exclude it from depedency, but I receive the same issue. struts2-core contains the OGNL dependency.
On Tomcat6 ad Tomcat7 servers it runs well as it expected.

Comment: Don't exclude `ognl-3.0.5`. Configure your app in websphere that app libs are used.

Comment: We're planning to use  Apache Geronimo (on Websphere Application Server).

Comment: Try to configure classloader as Parent_Last in the web module configuration options via WebSphere admin console.

Comment: Can you describe it more detailed? Our WebSphere admin can not find this parameter.

Comment: a geronimo-web.xml file had been added to the root folder in the generated war file.

Comment: Parameter is in `Enterprise Applications > yourApplication > Manage Modules > yourModule.war` and there you have `Class loader order`

Answer (score 0):

geronimo-web.xml file had been added to the root folder in the generated war file

The App_ID is the of my application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/web-2.0.1">
    <dep:environment xmlns:dep="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/deployment-1.2">
        <dep:moduleId>
            <dep:groupId>default</dep:groupId>
            <dep:artifactId>App_ID</dep:artifactId>
            <dep:version>1.0</dep:version>
            <dep:type>war</dep:type>
        </dep:moduleId>
        <dep:hidden-classes>
            <dep:filter>ognl</dep:filter>
            <!--
            <dep:filter>org.apache.axis2</dep:filter>
            <dep:filter>javax.xml.bind</dep:filter>
            <dep:filter>javax.xml.ws</dep:filter>
            -->
        </dep:hidden-classes>
    </dep:environment>
    <context-root>/App_ID</context-root>
</web-app>
```